# PHP / MySQL query - if current time/date is in schedule

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, calendar

I'm trying to develop a simple php based schedule ...

This is my database table:
[image]

Let's say that current time/date is: `2012-03-21 02:00:00`

PHP script should echo: **`Meeting 2`**

I have a part of the script, but no idea what to do next

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("schedule", $con);

$current_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  echo $row['Subject'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**How to filter query, to mach current time and scheduled subject? Thank you!**

(if `current_time` is between `StartTime` and `EndTime` - echo it's `Subject`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE NOW() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime
```

Comment: Why LIMIT 1? The OP's example only returned one result because there was only one matching result in the dataset.

Comment: PERFECT! tested and confirmed! Thank you for fast response!

Comment: @liquorvicar I wrote this before question edit (or I have no read question last row :) ). However ORDER BY and LIMIT can be deleted. You're right

Answer (score 1):

Try `select * from events where StartTime <= NOW() and EndTime >= NOW()`
`NOW()` will give you current time in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following query

```
select * from events where current_time between startTime and endTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE current_time between startTime and endTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

The mysql BETWEEN operator may be of some use.

```
$startDate = gmdate('Y/m/d/ H:i:s','2012-03-21 02:00:00');
$endDate   = gmdate('Y/m/d/ H:i:s','2012-03-21 02:23:59');

$sql = 'select subject from events 
  where startTime between "'.gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", $startDate) . 
  '" and "' . gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", $endDate).'") ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're going to have to convert your StartTime and EndTime into a timestamp using strtotime so you can compare it to the current time (same thing goes for current time):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Then just say if current_time > StartTime AND current_time < EndTime echo Subject.
Something like this should work:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $startTime = strtotime($row['StartTime']);
  $endTime = strtotime($row['StartTime']);
  if (strtotime($current_time) > $startTime && strtotime($current_time) < $endTime
      echo $row['Subject'];
}
```

Comment: Derp, didn't think about doing the SQL statement first, haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
putenv("TZ=Asia/Calcutta");  // To Set TimeZone
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "select * from events where '$now' between StartTime and EndTime";
```