# MongoDB / PHP query- if current time/date is in schedule

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime

I have entries that store the start and end time of an event. I'm trying to query with MongoDate to find all events that are happening at the current time of the query.

The same question is answered here, but for MongoDB instead of MySQL:
[PHP / MySQL query - if current time/date is in schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801112/php-mysql-query-if-current-time-date-is-in-schedule)

So far, all I can find is the reverse kind of query for MongoDate:

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2010-01-15 00:00:00"));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime("2010-01-30 00:00:00"));

// find dates between 1/15/2010 and 1/30/2010
$collection->find(array("ts" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end)));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple actually: instead of checking for range, just check for equality:

```
$now = new MongoDate();
$collection->find(array('ts' => $now));
```

... as it looks like you don't store event start and end information in different properties. If you actually would like to, use two properties: 't_start' and 't_end', and fill the latter only when event is actually finished. When this scheme is applied, query becomes a bit more complex:

```
$collection->find(array(
  't_end'   => array('$exists' => false)
));
```